# Piping for a computer understanding

Tags: c, architecture, system, piping

I understand that in piping **a < b > c** means  to use the data of file b for input to program a instead of stdin, and write the output of program b to the file c instead of stdout.

What I dont understand is how to give a piping command to use the data of file b for input to program a instead of stdin and write the output of program a to the file c instead of stdout.

Where would b be a be placed in this one?

I have a < b for the stdin but dont figure a way to get the stdout.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Piping is attaching standard output of a process to the standard input of another, using `|`. What you have there is redirection. And it has nothing to do with C per se, it's a feature of the surrounding environment.

Comment: So what I wrote above is actually what im looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not actually piping, rather it's redirection of the input and output streams.

Piping is taking the standard output of one process and attaching it to the standard input of another process, such as with:

```
seq 1 5 | sort -r
```

which generates the numbers 1 through 5 (in that order) then sorts them in reverse order, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> seq 1 5
1
2
3
4
5

pax> seq 1 5 | sort -r
5
4
3
2
1
```

The sequence:

```
prog <infile >outfile
```

runs the `prog` program in a process and gets its standard input from the `infile` *file* and sends its standard output to the `outfile` file. Only one process is involved.

To "use the data of file b for input to program a instead of stdin and write the output of program a to the file c instead of stdout", you would use:

```
a <b >c
```

exactly as you have. You'll note in my examples I don't have a space between the redirection character (`<` or `>`) and the file name - I believe this makes the relationship clearer since `>xyzzy` means "send output to the `xyzzy` file".

You erroneous assertion about what `a < b > c` does ("to use the data of file b for input to program a instead of stdin, and write the output of program b to the file c instead of stdout") would be more apt to the *separate* commands:

```
a <b ; b >c
```

with no real connection between the `a` and `b` programs.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
a < b > c
```

as you mentioned in your question. This does not do what you mean it does: it does not use b as input for a and c as output for b. This uses b as input for a and c as output for a.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong.

A command such as

```
a <b >c
```

only is one command, namely `a`. The input to `a` is from file `b` and the output is to file `c`.

There is no command `b` (or `c`) being executed.

So in short, that command already does what you want.

Comment: Really? I thought putting b > c next to each other writes b to the file c instead of stdout

Comment: @user2127663 Yes, but _only_ if that's the complete command line. The redirection operations are not chaining programs.